# How do I get Laravel Echo to work on production?

Tags: laravel, server, laravel-echo, namecheap, pusher-js

I'm having trouble with Laravel Echo (I think). I've built a vue chat app that works locally. 
I've even cloned it onto another machine and got it working fine. But when I get it onto production, it's not working. 
I'm not running npm on the server, I'm just doing a run npm prod before committing and pushing to the server. 
For some reason it just doesn't work though. The messages are getting through to pusher as I can see them in the debug console.

Here's some of the code:

```
mounted() { 
    console.log('mounted');

    Echo.private(`messages.${this.user.id}`)
        .listen('NewMessage', (e) => {
            console.log('in echo');
            this.hanleIncoming(e.message);
        });

    axios.get('/contacts')
        .then((response) => {
            this.contacts = response.data;
        });
},
methods: {
    startConversationWith(contact) {
        this.updateUnreadCount(contact, true);

        axios.get(`/conversation/${contact.id}`)
            .then((response) => {
                this.messages = response.data;
                this.selectedContact = contact;
            })
    },

    saveNewMessage(message) {
        console.log(message);
        this.messages.push(message);
    },

    hanleIncoming(message) {
        if (this.selectedContact && message.from == this.selectedContact.id) {
            console.log('inside if of handleincoming');
            this.saveNewMessage(message);
            return;
        }

        this.updateUnreadCount(message.from_contact, false);
    }
}
```

When local I get all the console.logs, but on prod I only get one and that's because saveMessage gets called on hitting enter from the message chat window. Do I need to install something on the server to get echo to work since I'm not doing npm install on the server. I don't think node is even installed. How can I get echo to work on production?  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You got it working ? facing the same issue let me know if you make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you started echo server on production?

Comment: Well I think the point is that I should be able to run a production build locally using npm, and then it would work.  Are you saying I have to have an echo server running for it to work?

Comment: You will need to run a compatible Socket.IO server. Laravel does not include a Socket.IO server implementation; however, a community driven Socket.IO server is currently maintained at the [tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server](https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server) GitHub repository.

View in Socket.io section in [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/broadcasting#introduction)

Comment: I noted in the question that I’m using pusher and the messages are getting to the debug console.  From what it looks like in the documentation, composer require pusher/pusher-php-server "~3.0" rather than using the echo server with socket